# superimpose normal density curve to histogram malfunctioning (base r)

Tags: r, histogram, normal-distribution

I am using base R, and had a code for teaching about normal distribution, and have ran the code successfully many times.

Now, however, when I superimpose the normal density curve, it doesn't seem to function properly.

Here is an example code:

```
set.seed(100)

data <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)

hist(data, main = "Normal Distribution", xlab = "X", ylab = "Frequency", col = "444", xlim=c(-4,4))
```

[image]

Now I try to superimpose a density curve over the plot, using the `density()` command:

```
lines(density(data), col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

As you see, the line is flat, and I am perplexed as to why? So I tried another method:

```
x <- seq(-4, 4, length.out = 100)
lines(x, dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1), col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

But I get the same result.

Any thoughts why it's not working properly?

Comment: You've plotted a histogram of the frequency of your observed data.  The "area under the curve" is therefore `n`, the number of observations.  The area under the curve of the Normal density is `1` by definition.  You have a mismatch in scales.  You need either to convert your histogram to represent proportions, or scale your density to reflect the number of observations.  [The clue is in the values on the y-axis.  The value of N(0, 1) at 0 (the mode) is only 0.4 or thereabouts.

Comment: @Limey thanks.  Given your comment, I would think that the second line of code I tried should work, because, how I am seeing it, this is exactly what you are explaining here: ```x <- seq(-4, 4, length.out = 100)
lines(x, dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1), col = "red", lwd = 2)``` . I seem to be missing your clue, but I will reflect on it and see if the answer all of sudden comes to mind. I appreciate the advice

Comment: @Limey: I got it :) Your 0.4 comment bothered me, and now I see it.  I should have set ```freq=FALSE```.  I have done this, and it now works!

Answer (score 0):

The answer came to me thanks to one of the users comments.

Using base R, the `hist()` function will not plot a probability function by default, which is what needed here.  Thus, if I set `freq=F` the code will worked.

Here is the correct answer:

```
set.seed(100)

data <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)


hist(data, main = "Normal Distribution", xlab = "X", ylab = "Frequency", col = "444", xlim=c(-4,4), freq = F)

lines(density(data), col ='777', lwd = 2)
```

[image]